# How do I display my object's data in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

Here is my code:

```
void Main() {
    List<Restaurant> RestaurantData = new List<Restaurant>();
}

class Restaurant {
    public int Id;
    public List<Complaint> Complaints = new List<Complaints>();
}

class Complaint {
    public string Name;
    public string Address;
    public int Age;
    public DateTime ComplaintDate;
}
```

I'd like to present the data contained in RestaurantData in the DataGridView control. First, I'd like to show the Restaurant's ID, followed by the number of Complaints against the restaurant so that it looks something like this (where the ID is in column A, and the Name is in Column B, and so forth):

```
ID1, Name, Address, Age, Date
(space), Name, Address, Age, Date
(space), Name, Address, Age, Date
ID2, Name, Address, Age, Date
(space), Name, Address, Age, Date
(space), Name, Address, Age, Date
```

Every restaurant has at least 1 complaint, and some restaurants may have many complaints.  But in all cases, I want the Restaurant's ID to show up only once (with its complaints to follow).  My past usage of DataGridView has been limited to dataGridView1.DataSource = (some array). However, the information I want to present this time is clearly not an array so I'm stuck.

```
 var ds = (from r in RestaurantData
           from c in RestaurantData.Complaint
           select new {Id = r.Id, Address =c.Address, Age = c.Age, Name = c.Name, Date = c.ComplaintDate}
             ).ToList();

    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
```

Currently, this fills every row with the corresponding Restaurant ID.  How do I adjust the above query such that the restaurant ID only shows up once?

Comment: Is there a known maximum number of complaints per restaurant (that you want to display on a line).

Comment: @Servy.  No, I don't know the max number of complaints in advance.

Comment: @phan Is it an option to throw all of the data for all of the complaints into a single column?  You lose the headers, but keep the info.

Comment: @Ahmed See my added LINQ query.

Comment: @Servy The data has to be broken out in their respective columns and not lumped all together in a single column.

Comment: @phan I was confused by the lack of line breaks in your display of the results; I thought you wanted them all on one line, not on subsequent lines.  That's a much harder problem, this is fairly doable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're *almost* there.  You have almost exactly what you want, and are getting it in an appropriate manor, but what you really need to know is if a particular complaint is the first item in that list.  The way to get that is to use the overload of `Select` when selecting from `complaints` that has an index as a parameter.  To do that you need to use method syntax, rather than query syntax, so that accounts for the majority of the changes.

Once you have that index adjusting `ID` is a pretty trivial check.

```
var data = restaurantData.SelectMany(restaurant =>
    restaurant.Complaints.Select((complaint, index) => new
    {
        ID = index == 0 ? restaurant.Id.ToString() : "",
        complaint.Name,
        complaint.Address,
        complaint.Age,
        Date = complaint.ComplaintDate,
    }));
```

Comment: Sorry about the formatting.  When I set dataGridView1.DataSource = data nothing shows up.  But when I step through the code and look at the contents of 'data' it looks like the way I wanted (I expand the Results View).  How do I get the data to display in the DataGrid control?  I think this has something to do with enumerate the IEnumerable but to be honest I have no idea what this means.

Comment: @phan I don't know what problem you're having.  This is the proper data, as you yourself confirmed, so it sounds like some other problem elsewhere in your application, possibly related to how the DGV is configured.  In any case, it's a separate question.

Comment: You're right.  I fixed my DGV and everything works now!  Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible to use OrderBy in the code above?  I don't know where to insert OrderBy so that the results are ordered by Restaurant ID (ascending number) and then by Complaint.Name, and Complaint.Date.

Comment: @phan Just call `OrderBy` before the `SelectMany` call.

Comment: var data = restaurantData.OrderBy(x => x.ID).ThenBy(y => y.complaint.Name).SelectMany....I'm getting an error on the complaint.name.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @phan There is no complaint name at that point; you said you only wanted to order based on the restaurant's information.  If you want to order on the individual complaints but only within each restaurant  you'll need to order before the call to `Select`.